# For vue, why div's remove event invalid?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I want study v-for and template by vue manual.
For v-for and components, My code:

```
<div id="app-7">
  <input v-model="newTodoText" v-on:keyup.enter="addNewTodo" placeholder="Add a todo">
  <ul>
    <todo-item2
        v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
        v-bind:key="todo.id"
        v-bind:id="todo.id"
        v-bind:title="todo.title"
        v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)">
    </todo-item2>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My main.js code is:

```
Vue.component('todo-item2', {
  template: '<li>{{ title }}-{{ id }}<div v-on:remove="testRemove"><button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">X</button></div></li>',
  props: ['title', 'id'],
  methods: {
    testFunc: function () {
      console.log('div click event trigger')
    },
    testRemove: function () {
      console.log('div remove event trigger')
    }
  }
}) 

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    newTodoText: '',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Do the dishes'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Take out the trash'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Mow the lwan'
      }
    ],
    nextTodoId: 4
  },
  methods: {
    addNewTodo: function () {
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.nextTodoId++,
        title: this.newTodoText
      })
      this.newTodoText = ''
    }
  }
})
```

I found that click button cause to remove li label, so I know li's remove event is triggered. But I don't understand why div'remove event is not triggered. Who can tell my $emit('remove')?
What's mean for $emit(args) triggered current instance event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div component doesn't have `remove` event. If you change to `click` event (`v-on:click="testRemove"`), you can see console log `div remove event trigger`

```
Vue.component('todo-item2', {
  template: '<li>{{ title }}-{{ id }}<div v-on:click="testRemove"><button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">X</button></div></li>',
  props: ['title', 'id'],
  methods: {
    testFunc: function () {
      console.log('div click event trigger')
    },
    testRemove: function () {
      console.log('div remove event trigger')
    }
  }
})
```

By default, Vue on support `DOM events` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

**Updated**

`v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')"` will call this.$emit event. Here, this will be `todo-item2` component. It only emit event to parent of `todo-item2`

Comment: I still don't understand it. I look up https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp, actually no remove event. Why v-on:remove for todo-item2 is valid?

Comment: So I click button, what heppen? Actually, I click button cause to li's v-on:remove event happen.

Comment: `v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')"` will call `this.$emit` event. Here, `this` will be `todo-item2` component. It only emits event to parent of `todo-item2`.

Comment: It only eimit event to parent of todo-item2? Should not todo-item2 fix this event?

Comment: `todo-item2` is `li` element. Here, `this` is `li` element. `this.$emit` will emit event to parent of `li`. If you listen to `remove` event in `div` element (parent of button, not `li` element), event is not captured here.

Comment: The 'remove' event will be fixed by li's parent? ul ?

Comment: It's Vue's parent component, where `todo-item2` is used. Here is `div#app-7`

Comment: Oh, I got it. I still have a problem that who execute `todos.splice`. If it is `div#app`, why v-on:remove bind li?

Comment: `todos.splice` is execute by Vue component which has template `div#app-7`.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you very much!